# Change the login screen

Tags: 14.04, login, lock-screen

I'm new to Ubuntu and I gotta say it's way much better than Windows. I just have a question, can I change the login screen like one of these? If you can teach me I would really appreciate it. I searched the internet but it's all blurry I didn't know how to do it. Thanks :)

[image: CIA lock screen]

Answer (score 1):

The only think you can get close to this is by just changing the login screen wallpaper. You can do that by installing  **Simple LightDM Manager**
Open terminal and run these following commands. (remember to press enter after each command)

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:claudiocn/slm`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y simple-lightdm-manager`

Open the newly installed application, called Simple LightDM Manager, from Unity Dash and select the wallpaper you want to set as default, for both your desktop and login screen, by clicking the "Location" button. You can even change the logo.

For additional settings like changing the theme and all, you can install the Unity tweak tool from the appstore.

---

> *One machine can do the work of fifty ordinary men. No machine can do the work of one extraordinary man. -Elbert Hubbard*

Comment: @Alexi if this answer was useful for you, kindly mark it as solved. Have a nice day dear.

Comment: Okk... Sorry I didn't know that 

Comment: @Alexi To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in green.